# Openwrt Curl on MR-3020

Tags: networking, openwrt

I can't install curl on my MR-3020 because there is not enough space. This is a problewm for all devices with small boards

Even when I remove all the non essential packages, it does not have space for the dependent packages. Common solution is to use an external USB drive but that's not an option for me because I use the USB drive for a modem.

Comment: Unless you're building your image from source, removing packages doesn't have the effect you desire: It even reduces available space a bit.     du /overlay  shows those files which, when removed, give you some extra space. This assumes that you're using a squashfs image, not a jffs2 image (with which you'd have even less space to start with, as compression is worse). If possible at all, see whether the busybox provided wget can be used, as this doesn't require extra installation or additional space

Comment: I moved to wget. Much better indeed!! That said I still think downloading the packages to RAM is cool!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much struggle I found a solution [here](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=46555) that I thought I would share with the community:

Edit `/etc/rc.local` with:

```
opkg update
opkg install curl -d ram
rm /tmp/opkg-lists/*
```

So that it would just install it to ram on reboot so it would be available. You may need to edit your exports so it can find it in the ram destination.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/lib:/usr/lib:/tmp/lib:/tmp/usr/lib'
export PATH='/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/tmp/usr/bin:/tmp/usr/sbin'
```

This way I am able to use it as if it were installed locally and not just re-installed on reboot.